# Prove that a sequence of complex numbers $z_{n} = (a_{n},b_{n})$ converges to $z = (a,b)$ iff $a_{n}$ converges to $a$ and $b_{n}$ converges to $b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

The complex numbers $\textbf{C}$ with the distance $d(w,z) = |w - z|$ form a metric space. If $(z_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty} = (a_{n},b_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of complex numbers, and $z = (a,b)$ is another complex number, then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_{n} = z$ in this metric space iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n} = a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n} = b$.

**My solution**

Let us suppose first that $z_{n}\to z$. For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds an $N\geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow |z_{n} - z| = \sqrt{(a_{n} - a)^{2} + (b_{n} - b)^{2}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
since $|a_{n} - a| \leq |z_{n} - z|$ and $|b_{n} - b| \leq |z_{n} - z|$, we conclude that $a_{n}\to a$ and $b_{n}\to b$.

Conversely, let us suppose that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there are $N_{1}\geq 0$ and $N_{2}\geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
n\geq N_{1} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - a| < \varepsilon/2\\\\
n\geq N_{2} \Rightarrow |b_{n} - b| < \varepsilon/2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Thus if we choose $N = \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$, we may claim that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds an $N\geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow |z_{n} - z| \leq |a_{n} - a| + |b_{n} - b| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Am I reasoning correctly? Could someone provide another way to prove it?

Comment: You can find a proof of this here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Convergent_Complex_Sequence

Comment: Looks good to me. You probably want $<$ rather than $\leq$ in your cases environment for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited it.